# Does Copying of const shared memory objects make sense in Multithreading

Tags: multithreading

This question is not about thread savety. 
The objects I am talking about are const vectors (of point clouds) used as input in a multithreaded routine. As they are const, I can share them without worrying about thread savety.

It is about getting better runtime performance. My multithreaded routine is by far not as fast as I expect it to be. I run 11 parallel threads (maximum number is 12 on my six core), but I only get something like half the runtime of the non multithreaded approach.
The counter argument to make copies (inefficient in memory usage) can also be ignored. Memory is in my case not an issue.

My routine relies on a lot of spatial queries on the input vector. As the vector is shared, I expect the loss of efficiency here.

My question, before I modify my complex code is: If I generate 11 copies of the vector for my 11 parallel threads, will this be only a minor improvement, because all 11 objects still share the same physical memory? My knowledge of the hardware of a computer is too limited to answer this question.